# HTTPS Call exception "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format."

Tags: c#, https, windows-services

While making REST api calls(with https scheme) from windows service, I am getting exception which states "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.". The said exception simply goes away on assignment of Domain User as Service Logon Account.
[image]

Also, I am not getting any exception while in development phase(Visual studio 2015,C#).

```
***Code Snippet:***
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
 var response = await Client.PostAsync("https://auth.brivo.com/oauth/token", httpContent, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

***Exception Thrown:***
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at Sisco.FastPass.AccessControl.Brivo.HttpClientHelper.<PostFormDataRequest>d__5`2.MoveNext()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
            at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146232800
            Message=**The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.**
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link as below and check enable ssl protocol section:
https://www.limilabs.com/blog/the-handshake-failed-due-to-an-unexpected-packet-format